# How to hide a print() or that it does not execute in under certain circumstances

Tags: python

I want to know if it's possible in python to not run an part of the code

```
from random import randint
def replay():
    réponse = input("Want to replay?")
    if réponse == "Yes".lower():
        jeu()
    if réponse == "No".lower():
        exit()
def jeu():
    choice = int(randint(1, 10))
    userchoice = int(input("I think of a number between 1 and 10, guess it: \n"))
    if choice <= userchoice:
        print("The number is too high")
    if choice >= userchoice:
        print("The number is too law")
    if choice == userchoice:
        print("Well done the number was" ,userchoice,)
        replay()
    if choice != userchoice:
        while True:
            userchoice = int(input("Try again\n"))
            if choice <= userchoice:
                print("The number is too high")
            if choice >= userchoice:
                print("The number is too law")
            if choice == userchoice:
                print("Well done the number was " ,userchoice,)
                replay()
jeu()
```

When I guess the number it gives me this:

[image: output]

and I don't want to see "The number is to high" and "the number is too low" at the same time. How to do so ? How can we hide this or prevent this part of code from running in that condition?

Comment: Use ```if....elif....elif``` instead of ```if...if...if```. They are 3 separate blocks

Comment: You'll also want to use < and >, not <= and >=.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this operator:

```
>=,
<=
```

This two operators also tell python to check if a particular number is greater, less or **equal to** the next operand.

when you input an integer which is equal to the random number, it is equal to the random number. And 3 separate blocks if `if` created 3 new control statement which are independent of each other.

So the condition `>=` and `<=` is always met. hence it prints "it's to high" or "it's to low"

```
if choice < userchoice:
    print("The number is too high")
elif choice > userchoice:
    print("The number is too law")
elif choice == userchoice:
    print("Well done the number was" ,userchoice,)
    replay()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this block:

```
if choice <= userchoice:
    print("The number is too high")
if choice >= userchoice:
    print("The number is too law")
if choice == userchoice:
    print("Well done the number was" ,userchoice,)
```

It will fail for the case when `choice` and `userchoice` is same. Each of the 3 conditions will meet then and all 3 conditions will execute.

However, replace the `redundant` checking with `lambda` function and remove the misplaced use of `while` loop with repetitive code. You can *refactor* your code as follows to have a more decent look:

```
from random import randint

def replay():
    réponse = input("Want to replay?")
    if réponse.lower() == "Yes".lower():
        jeu()
    if réponse.lower() == "No".lower():
        exit()
        
def jeu():
    choice = int(randint(1, 10))
    print("I think of a number between 1 and 10, guess it:")
    while True:
        userchoice = int(input())
        if choice == userchoice:
            print("Well done the number was" ,userchoice,)
            replay()
        else:
            f = lambda c, uc: print("The number is too high") if c < uc else print("The number is too low")
            f(choice, userchoice)
            print("Try Again:")


jeu()
```